# Best way to add a custom view as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have custom view with associated .xib file say A. Now I want to add this view as subview to B. What is the best way to do it? I know following ways

1. `A *aView =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"A" owner:self
       options:nil] lastObject]; 
   [b addSubView:a];`
2. Add

   `self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"A" owner:self
       options:nil] lastObject];` in `initWithFrame:` method.
   Then

   `A *a = [[A alloc]init];

   [b addSubView:a];`

3- Refer http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading/.

I prefer option 3, as it reduces a lot of effort while using auto layout. Is it the best way? also include why is/isn't it the best way?

Any help is greatly appreciated. And if there is another way please add details here.

Comment: You can change the `UIView` class to your custom class in the `IB`. Then you don't need alloc init methods. :)

Comment: Changing UIView class to custom class in the IB will not load the custom nib file. To load custom nib you want either use method 3 or want to add it as subview in the awakefromNib: method

Comment: From the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib, `awakefromNib:` method runs *after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized*

Comment: So, you can load or work with the objects under `awakefromNib:` and you does not have to add customView as subView to its parentView.

Comment: I have already tried this method. Please try it yourself and verify.

Comment: I have tried and used it already

Comment: It would be great if you can post the details as answer here. If possible with code. Sure I am not the only one who is don't know this method.

Comment: Changing the class to custom class in IB, doesn't mean that you are adding it as a subView, but if you want that the child class will acquire the same frame as of parentView, it is a best practice to use custom classes instead of using at subView.